# Scrolling a list using jQuery UI Draggable and jQuery Touch Punch on an iPad is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

See the jsfiddle below:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38vgc/4/)

When viewing this on a desktop browser scrolling works as I expect it to. You can use the scrollbars to scroll the list, and you can click and drag the boxes without the list scrolling.

My problems occur when I try scrolling this list on an iPad. Each time you touch a box in the list it's already set to draggable thus you cannot swipe through the list and simply drag and drop one of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this to work? Maybe an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);" data-r="107"
    data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
    <div class="color" style="background-color: rgb(107, 163, 93);"
    data-r="107" data-g="163" data-b="93"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroller {
    width: 317px;
    height: 325px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.color {
    margin:5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".color").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    helper: "clone",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot add a comment I hope you don't downvote me as this is only a suggestion based on my own experience.

Try using https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch.  
Some time ago I needed to create something like you did and make it compatible to all mobile devices and this helped a lot.